# Simple incremental counter in mysql query

Tags: mysql

My Query:

```
SET @rank = 0;
SELECT Jobs.ID, Jobs.StatusID, (@rank:=@rank+1) AS Rank
FROM Jobs
INNER JOIN JobStatuses ON Jobs.StatusID = JSID
INNER JOIN JobStatusGroups ON Jobs.SGrID = JSGID
WHERE Jobs.StatusID = 3
ORDER BY JobTitle DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Results in:

```
1010 3 1
1011 3 2
1013 3 4
1014 3 5
1016 3 7
```

Should result in:

```
1010 3 1
1011 3 2
1013 3 3
1014 3 4
1016 3 5
```

How can I make `@rank` only increment if row is actually being inserted? I tried `cross join` did not work. I also tried the following:

```
SELECT Jobs.ID, Jobs.StatusID, (@rank:=@rank+1) AS Rank
FROM Jobs, (SELECT @rank := 0) tempRank
INNER JOIN JobStatuses ON Jobs.StatusID = JSID
INNER JOIN JobStatusGroups ON Jobs.SGrID = JSGID
WHERE Jobs.StatusID = 3
ORDER BY JobTitle DESC
LIMIT 5
```

But gives me an error saying `Jobs.StatusID` does not exist.

Comment: @CGio..can you try my updated answer for old question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of setting it outside cross join it in the select (i prefer cross join just so its easier to read aka i know where im creating the variable) that way the count wont be messed up

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO MyTable(MyID, UserID, JobID, StatusID, SortOrder)
SELECT :myid, :userid, Jobs.ID, Jobs.StatusID, (@rank:=@rank+1) AS Rank
FROM Jobs
INNER JOIN JobStatuses ON Jobs.StatusID = JSID
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rank := 0) temp
LEFT JOIN JobStatusGroups ON Jobs.SGrID = JSGID
WHERE ...
ORDER BY JobTitle DESC
```

on terms of performance I haven't ever noticed performance issues with using the variables instantiation inside a join on the table

one thing you can try is maybe the ORDER BY is messing up the order / count so you can try encapsulating it in a subselect

```
SELECT ID, StatusID, (@rank:=@rank+1) AS Rank
FROM
(   SELECT Jobs.ID, Jobs.StatusID
    FROM Jobs
    INNER JOIN JobStatuses ON Jobs.StatusID = JSID
    INNER JOIN JobStatusGroups ON Jobs.SGrID = JSGID
    WHERE Jobs.StatusID = 3
    ORDER BY JobTitle DESC
    LIMIT 5
)t
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rank := 0) temp
```

Comment: Can you explain on how the `CROSS JOIN` works? Does it add overhead in terms of speed of the query?

Comment: @GGio yup :) from what I know there isn't any issues with it.. but I'd say try it out and see if it performs any slower just to be sure

Comment: I just tried that and did not work. It still skipped by 2 or 3 randomly.

Comment: are you executing more than one thing per each row? and could you post a sqlfiddle with some sample data? hard to do much here with what I have to go on

Comment: updated my question please look. Removed insert part, i just want to get it to work for select so there is no confusion with `INSERT IGNORE` and `ON DUPLCIATE KEY UPDATE`

Comment: @GGio can you provide a sqlfiddle with some dummy data? so I can test it myself? a lot of the times its hard to figure this issue out without being able to manipulate it myself

Comment: @GGio also try running my other query... you may have issues with the ordering of your rows causing the count to be off.

Comment: Ruddel that seems to work. Executes slower but numbers are correct now. Thank you. I will try to optimize the speed by playing around with it.

Comment: @GGio awesome... yea sometimes ordering can cause issues along with a lot of other things lol... the query itself shouldnt be much slower since you are just selecting from that but yea it will be a little slower

Answer (score 0):

Try This updated one:

```
SET @rank = 0;
INSERT INTO MyTable(MyID, UserID, JobID, StatusID, SortOrder)
SELECT myid, userid, Jobs.ID, Jobs.StatusID, (@rank:=@rank+1) AS Rank
FROM Jobs
INNER JOIN JobStatuses ON Jobs.StatusID = JobStatuses.JSID
LEFT JOIN JobStatusGroups ON Jobs.SGrID = JobStatusGroups.JSGID
 ON DUPLICATE KEY update MyID=IF((@rank:=@rank-1) <> NULL IS NULL, VALUES(MyID), NULL);
```

Comment: its still invalid.. look into insert with a select... the "values" keyword doesn't work with a statement like that

Comment: @Karunakar but what if there is no duplicate key and it just has to insert?

Comment: it will get inserted and rank get updated correctly....if row is a duplicate as we incremented in select we are doing decrement..am i correct?

Comment: @Karunakar nope.. thats what the IGNORE is for :)

Comment: Updated my question. please look

Comment: ignore case is differnt i think...in case of ignore rank gets updated first...then tries to insert ...if its duplicate that row get ignored. but rank not decremented ..am i correct?

Comment: i understood your question @GGio..try this